# What is the adequate fee for a reveal operation?

Tags: account, transfer, reveal, fee

When transferring funds to a non-revealed Tezos account, one must pay a "reveal fee".

- What is the optimal value to use for this fee?
- Or is this a fixed amount?
- What would be the adequate fee for a reveal operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question as stated confuses different things.

A "reveal" operation is an operation that writes on the chain the public key associated with a public key hash for an implicit account. The fee associated with this operation is up for the sender to decide, though most bakers implement default minimum fees (in this case it is currently 1267µꜩ).

The creation of a new account by sending tokens to an implicit address is not a "reveal" operation as the public key needs not be known in this operation. However, it does trigger the creation of an implicit account on the chain. Storage cost has to be paid, and it is *not* a part of the transaction fee. It is deducted directly from the account making the transaction, though it is subject to a cap specified by the sender. The default value for the storage cost incurred is indeed 0.257 XTZ.

Comment: Thank you both. My intention is, indeed, specify a fee to cover the costs of a  creation of a new account when sending tokens to it.

Answer (score 4):

The fee for adding a new account to the global state (`--burn-cap` with `tezos-client`) is 0.257 XTZ.

The origination burn is calculated as `Tez_repr.(cost_per_byte *? (Int64.of_int origination_size))`.

`cost_per_byte` is 0.001 XTZ. It is 1000 mutez and `1,000,000 mutez == 1 tez`.

`origination_size` is 257.

Due to that the resulting cost for an origination of a completely new account is 257,000 mutez or 0.257 tez.

This is defined in `proto_alpha/lib_protocol/fee_storage.ml`, `proto_alpha/lib_protocol/constants_repr.ml`, and `proto_alpha/lib_protocol/qty_repr.ml`

Comment: That's incorrect, the origination burn is not part of the transaction fee.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I have edited the above answer to clarify that the fee that I describe there is for adding a new account to the state.

Comment: I suggest keeping the terminology separate: "Fee" means paid to the baker. "Burn" means destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

In athens (proto004) the updated fees are available here

https://github.com/keefertaylor/TezosKit/blob/master/docs/AthensProtocolFees.md